# How can I make a FormatConversionProvider for MPEG-4 audio?

Tags: java, audio, mp4, mpeg-4

I would love to extend an old Java application [dump3](http://dump3.sourceforge.net/) that identifies potential duplicate mp3 files by calculating audio fingerprints.  From what I can tell rooting through the code, it handles any audio format that can be converted via a registered [FormatConversionProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/FormatConversionProvider.html).

Finding anything that plays the more modern iTunes default mp4 files through Java took some googling, I ended up with [JAAD](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/) and [jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/).  I even looked at the Java bindings for VLC.  Great, I can play audio.  But none seem to support a FormatConversionProvider!  Does anyone know how to plug tab A into slot B and enable a FormatConversionProvider for mpeg-4 audio?